# Why doesn't a useEffect's callback function use current state? Is there a way for it to take current state?

Tags: reactjs

I have a custom input React component. The component is passed in an initialValue which is used for the initialization of it's own value state:

```
const CustomInput = ({initialValue}) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
```

When the component is unmounted, I want to perform some logic only if the value of the input has been changed from its' initial value.  I have this useEffect logic to try to do just that:

```
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        console.log({initialValue})
        console.log({value})  // this log of value is always equal to initialValue
        initialValue !== value && console.log('initial value changed') // this log never runs
    }
}, []);

console.log(value) // this log shows that value is changing correctly when the input element is used
```

However, the value variable within useEffect will always have the same value as initialValue, even though value will change correctly when the input is used.  It's like the useEffect is using a cached value from when the component first mounted instead of the current value.  What's going on here and is there an easy way to fix it or will I have to use useRef or something similar?

Comment: Add `value` to the dependency array

Comment: but I don't want the useeffect return logic to run everytime value is changed, only when it unmounts

Comment: You'll need to use a ref then, and an empty dependency array. In the function body, do `valueRef.current = value` and you can reference `valueRef.current` inside the cleanup function.